# Search for nested values in jsonb array with greater operator

Tags: postgresql, index-tuning, performance, json, postgresql-10, postgresql-performance

Here is the table definition (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE documents (
    document_id int4 NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    data_block jsonb NULL
);
```

Sample values:

```
INSERT INTO documents (document_id, data_block)
VALUES
   (878979, 
    '{"COMMONS": {"DATE": {"value": "2017-03-11"}},
     "PAYABLE_INVOICE_LINES": [
         {"AMOUNT": {"value": 52408.53}}, 
         {"AMOUNT": {"value": 654.23}}
     ]}')
 , (977656, 
    '{"COMMONS": {"DATE": {"value": "2018-03-11"}},
     "PAYABLE_INVOICE_LINES": [
         {"AMOUNT": {"value": 555.10}}
     ]}');
```

I want to search all documents where one of the `'PAYABLE_INVOICE_LINES'` elements contains a `'value'` greater than 1000.00.

My query is

```
select *
from documents d
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(d.data_block -> 'PAYABLE_INVOICE_LINES') as pil 
where (pil->'AMOUNT'->>'value')::decimal > 1000
```

But, as I want to limit to 50 documents, I have to group on the `document_id` and limit the result to 50.

With millions of documents, this query is very expensive - 10 seconds with 1 million.

I try to add a GIN index on the array of the jsonb object. But it seems it's applied only while using a jsonb operator like `@>`.

Do you have some ideas to have better performance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is generally hard to optimize: no direct operator or index support for `jsonb` for this kind of test.

`EXISTS` should at least be faster than what you have, while also avoiding duplicate rows (where multiple array elements match) and the additional (redundant) column `pil` in the result:

```
SELECT *
FROM   documents d
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM jsonb_array_elements(d.data_block -> 'PAYABLE_INVOICE_LINES') pil 
   WHERE (pil->'AMOUNT'->>'value')::decimal > 1000
   );
```

Related:

- [Indexed range comparison of array key's value in row inside JSONB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202617/indexed-range-comparison-of-array-keys-value-in-row-inside-jsonb/202729#202729)
- [Speed up range test for key values nested in jsonb array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49532773/how-to-speed-up-queries-that-contain-joined-jsonb-array-elements-with-nested-j/49542329#49542329)

To make this ***faster by orders of magnitude***, extract the maximum value per row and save it redundantly or use an `IMMUTABLE` function in a very small and fast (but also specialized) expression index:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_doc_max_amout(jsonb)
  RETURNS numeric AS
$func$
   SELECT max((a->'AMOUNT'->>'value')::numeric)
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements($1) a
$func$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE INDEX documents_max_amount_idx
ON documents (f_doc_max_amout(data_block -> 'PAYABLE_INVOICE_LINES'));
```

Query (must match index expression):

```
SELECT *
FROM   documents d
WHERE  f_doc_max_amout(data_block -> 'PAYABLE_INVOICE_LINES') > 1000;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=83b0357f7cd845d8ae85d437b7325fb0)*

Comment: If an additional extension can be installed on the Postgres server, there is a special one called "jsquery" which extends regular JSON functionality, with GIN indexes support: https://github.com/postgrespro/jsquery. Packages for Ubuntu are available, as well as RPMs.

Comment: Yes, a very powerful extension from Postgres core contributors. It provides the missing functionality and index support for numeric comparison, among other things. Ultimate goal is to integrate it with core Postgres, Currently, it is not even in the extensions distributed with Postgres, yet. Packages [for Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/jsquery), Ubuntu and probably other distributions are available. Or you have to compile and install yourself. Impossible on most cloud services. Tedious on other installs.

Comment: Thanks ! This solution seems to be a good option for me. I will check for the extension too. Really thanks !

Comment: @Ryu: The `EXISTS` query, the expression index or both?

Comment: :) sorry, the solution with function with index. I think it is the best solution.