# Index for finding attributes in large JSONB array

Tags: postgresql, index, json

Based on [this original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array) and the [follow up question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71546/index-for-finding-combinations-of-attributes-in-json-array) from 2015.

Suppose I have a jsonb column `data` within a table `tracks`. This column holds an array with multiple keys e.g. `Artist` and `Title` in the JSON data. So we have something like:

```
INSERT INTO tracks (id, data)
VALUES (1, '[{"artist": "Simple Plan", "title": "Welcome to My Life"}]');
```

I understand that there are two Options to index the key `artist`:

1. GIN Index on data as a whole

   ```
   CREATE INDEX tracks_artists_gin_idx ON tracks
   USING GIN ((data));
   ```
2. A functional Index using for example json2arr described below

   ```
   CREATE INDEX tracks_artists_gin_idx ON tracks
   USING GIN (json2arr(data, 'artist'));

   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json2arr(_j json, _key text)
     RETURNS text[] LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
   'SELECT ARRAY(SELECT elem->>_key FROM json_array_elements(_j) elem)';

   --Index Usage:
   SELECT * FROM tracks
   WHERE  '{"Simple Plan"}'::text[] <@ (json2arr(data, 'artist'));
   ```

In my case, the `data` array is huge and has many more keys. So Option 1 is a bad idea. Is there a third option in 2021? Or is Option 2 still the way to go?

EDIT 16.02. :
This is the real world WHERE condition to be optimized:

```
 WHERE event @> '{"data":{"allFahrtabschnitt":[{"fahrtnummer":"62786"}]}}';
```

EDIT 22.02. :
Option 2 works so far and delivers great results. **I would still be interested if other Options exist that can use the standard jsonb Syntax.**

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION events.json2arr(_j jsonb, _key text)
     RETURNS text[] LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
 'SELECT ARRAY(SELECT elem->>_key FROM jsonb_array_elements(_j) elem)';

 CREATE INDEX interface_dk_fahrt_v4_fahrtnummer_gin_idx ON                events.interface_dk_fahrt_v4
     USING GIN (events.json2arr(event->'data'->'allFahrtabschnitt',      'fahrtnummer'::text));
 -- completed in 5 m 33 s 209 ms

 -- Selection - must match Index-Syntax!
 SELECT metaid FROM events.interface_dk_fahrt_v4_20210219
 WHERE 1=1
 AND '{"31650"}'::text[] <@ (events.json2arr(event->'data'-     >'allFahrtabschnitt', 'fahrtnummer'::text));
 -- 127ms

 -- Selection with incorrect Syntax -> Index isnt used
 SELECT metaid FROM events.interface_dk_fahrt_v4_20210219
 WHERE 1=1
 AND event @> '{"data":{"allFahrtabschnitt":[{"fahrtnummer":"31650"}]}}';
 -- 5 Minutes
```

EDIT 09.04. :
Here is a new option that we learned when looking into json_path_query that needs no custom functions:

```
CREATE INDEX interface_dk_fahrt_v4_fahrtnummer_gin_idx ON events.interface_dk_fahrt_v4 
USING gin (jsonb_path_query_array (event, '$.data.data.allFahrtabschnitt.fahrtnummer[*]));
```

Comment: What is the type of query you need to tune? What is the WHERE condition you are using? And what is that `json2arr` function doing?

Comment: The correct solution is the same in 2021 as it was in 2015: Don't model this with a large JSON in the database, but with a second database table and a foreign key relationship. Then the problem will go away.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your interest and comments! We are experimenting with Postgres as a schemaless NoSQL Event Store for Kafka Events. Each Kafka Event will get saved as jsonb in the data column. 
We are thinking about moving the required fields outside of the jsonb column. But it would cost us significantly more effort to design and build. So if there is a way to index it without using a schema or extra tables it is worth experimenting with. 

I added the json2arr function.

Comment: If there is a limited number of "top level keys", you could create one index for each to keep the indexes small, e.g. `create index ... on ( (event -> 'data' -> 'allFahrtabschnitt') )` then change the WHERE clause to `WHERE event -> 'data' -> 'allFahrtabschnitt' @> '[{"fahrtnummer":"62786"}]'`

Comment: That's a great hint. Sadly, the array is the biggest part of the event with lots of top-level keys.